# Fluid suddenly moves one direction + collision problem

Tags: fluid-simulation, collision

I'm using Blender's Mantaflow fluid simulation.

The fluid suddenly seems to move in one direction.
[image]

I din't give any velocity to the fluid source
[image]

My only guess is that the collider for the object below (floor) is too large...but then, why would the fluid only go in one direction, and why is it going through the wall (the left wall in the gif) ?

1. I checked that every normal points outside
2. Every effector (collider) has "sampling substeps" set to 3, and "surface thickness" set to 0 (I tried 0.5 but it didn't change anything)
3. I tried scaling every objects in case they were too small
4. The fluid source does not have any velocity
5. The fluid domain is large and encompasses everything

I'm completely new to Blender, so I may be missing something that may be completely obvious.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Here is the fluid domain settings:
[image]